# SignalR: detection used technology (webSockets or longPolling) in C# clients app

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client

How can I find out in code client's app (C#), which technology (polling or  WebSockets) is used to communicate with the server?

Answer (score 0):

From your hub you can call the following:

```
Context.QueryString["transport"]
```

It will return one of the following values: "webSockets", "serverSentEvents", "foreverFrame" or "longPolling".

I would say that your code shouldn't depend on which transport is being used, but it's might be useful in some cases (logging etc).